# How can I create a button in F# that contains both an image and text?

Tags: silverlight, button, f#

I have both a button, and an image as follows:

```
let btnFoo = new Button()
let imgBar = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri("images/whatever.png", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
```

I'd like the button content to contain some text, AND also the image.

I can do either of these two things just fine, but they don't get me both the text and the image on the button at the same time:

```
btnFoo.Content <- "Text"
btnFoo.Content <- imgBar
```

Neither of these things work:

```
btnFoo.Content <- "Text " + imgBar // compiler hates this
btnFoo.Content <- "Text ", imgBar // compiler is OK, but result is ugly since the image is rendered as the class text
```

I also can't set the background of the button to the image:

```
btnFoo.Background <- imgBar // compiler doesn't like this because Background expects a Media.Brush
```

Any thoughts/ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) and add your image along with [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) as it's children. then set this stack panel as buttons content. You may choose some other [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued) as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a panel (probably a StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal"). Set the content of the button to be the panel, and add the text and image to the panel.